# detecting and loading seperate site on mobile vertical orientation

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

At the moment, I've two versions of the site, for mobile and normal:

m.domain.com
domain.com

All mobile devices are detected via apache (tablets+phone) and redirected to m.domain.com

I'm wondering if it is possible, on some tablets with high resolution screen to have:

1. m.domain.com once rotated vertical
2. domain.com once rotated to horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way to do responsive and adaptive design is to have the same site for both mobile (phones and tablets) and desktop but use server side detection to serve up the html to that device, it saves bandwidth for the end user and it's easy to use.

**Server Side Detection: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect**

*There's a plugin for many popular CMSs and you can just use it directly.*

Example:

```
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){

     **** small slider with 3 images  ****

} elseif ( $detect->isTablet() ) {

    **** medium slider with 5 images  ****

} else {

  **** the large slider with lots of images that are large ****

}
```

I use this any place, you don't need to build your whole page with it. You can in your content area only show the slider for desktop with 10 images, the slider for tablets with 5 images, and no slider or a slider for phones with 3 images. There's many possibilities.

**CODE EXAMPLES https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples**

Comment: This defeats the idea of responsive, doesn't it? if I've server side code that dictates what html to serve, I'd rather serve seperate page altogether, whats the advantage of having same css?

Comment: You can have the same css since css is for viewport sizes and if you make them small viewport first, the smaller devices won't use them, but you don't have to have separate sites, it's easier to maintain. Adaptive sites are actually better for the end user than just responsive since responsive is visual, so that large image will get loaded if you use the img src= - display none will still load it.

Comment: I have the same css for my slider but the slider on phones show 3 of ten images, instead of all 10 images, it's the same slider just different html. This cannot be done with responsive media queries. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/09/improve-mobile-support-with-server-side-enhanced-responsive-design/

Comment: I get what you are saying, but it is no different structurally/philosophically/logically from having two versions of the site and serving them from different locations. Difference is between your approach and responsive yes, but difference between having dir/ mobile_dir/ and your suggested solution is none.

Comment: It's totally different, namely not two different sites to maintain/update, SEO, and so forth. It's why so many people are using that that script (php-mobile-detect) and why it's got a long list of CMS who have forked it. Why have two sites? Same CSS, different HTML only IF you want to.

Comment: Yes, you are saying not two sites to maintain, but you are still creating two different sets of html :) so it is still two different sites, no matter if you put html in different directories, or same html file.

Comment: Nope. It's on the same html page. You are not understanding and I'm not furthering this discussion. It's optional, you can use the hook on the home page and not anywhere else or use it everywhere. Use it just on one page or on 10 pages or just in the footer or header. Use it just for the slider or just for the large image portfolio but the rest of the page is the same for all devices.

Comment: It's a good answer. I'm still not buying the advantage of this for my use case. But it is handy tool to have :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With responsive websites you shouldn't need to have 2 domains. (I assume there is a reason for your doing this).

Responsive design uses media queries to determine how elements should display depending on factors like screen resolution.

When a user switches their screen from landscape the browser will change the design based on your media queries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm still debating which way to go. separate vs same + media queries. Reasoning to go in separate direction is that, desktop site is heavy with images, and has a lot of js that is not needed in mobile version.

Comment: In that case, you can use jQuery to capture when the screen resizes, $(window).resize(..), check the screen resolution at that point and redirect the user to the desktop site if the screen resolution is great enough. This may cause problems with your apache as it may redirect them back to the mobile site. You'll have to play around. For responsive pictures read this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/